# Use vmconnect from another AD domain

Tags: active-directory, rdp

I try to connect remotly to the KVM (console) of an Hyper-V Virtual Machine using vmconnect.exe but I'm dealing with some kind of a problem :

When I connect from a computer **within** the same AD of my Hyper-V Host, everything work fine but when I try to connect from a computer **not within** the same AD, wmconnect say that my RCP services is not running on the host

The problem is that it doesn't ask me for any credentials and so, i can't authenticate in the AD

Does someone have any clues ?

Comment: Why are you using the Hyper-V vmconnect.exe program instead of the traditional MSTSC.exe program across servers?

Answer (score 0):

When you are not in a domain (or on a different domain the same applies afaik), you still need to connect ***by name***, and it must be a simple name, not a fqdn.

In practice this probably means editing the `hosts` file on both the client and the server.

edit:

In your case you [may be able to](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/3ac6e9d6-6af7-4cbe-893f-2101563f9a14) achieve the same thing by establishing a trust relationship between the domains.